# Is it necessary to wrap <strong>, <em>, <b>, <i> inside <p> tag, if content is not paragraph?

Tags: css, xhtml, accessibility, semantic-markup, screen-readers

For example:

This is ok

```html
<div>
    <p>some <strong>long</strong> text</p>
    <strong>- end -</strong>
    <p>some long text</p>
</div>
```

Or this is more semantically correct?

```html
<div>
    <p>some <strong>long</strong> text</p>
    <p><strong>- end -</strong></p>
    <p>some long text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

If it isn't a paragraph, then it shouldn't be marked up as a paragraph. (The HTML specification explains [how to read the DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3) to determine what elements are allowed at a given point in a document.)

> `<p><strong>- end -</strong></p>`

… however, I don't know what this is. You should follow the normal rules for grammar.

Comment: <strong>- end -</strong> this is a indication of end of paragraph after each paragraph in MS word file which i got from client

Comment: There's a `<strong> - end - </strong>` at the end of *every paragraph*? That's...interesting. If they're using it like that *and* they want to keep the content, then `<br/><strong> - end - </strong></p>` is the answer. But I prefer David's -- just `</p>` and drop the thing, if they'll let you.

Comment: you mean even <strong> is valid but we should wrap in <p>.

Answer (score 7):

Academic answer: both are XHTML-compatible.
Practical answer: browsers won't give a sh@t about it

Answer (score 1):

If the content is not a paragraph, then it is not semantic to mark it as such.

If your end marker is designed to be read, then it is debatable whether or not it is actually a paragraph or not. If it's not designed to be read, then it shouldn't be marked up with reading-oriented tags like `<strong>`, but instead should be in a span or div with a stylesheet applied to make the font weight bold.

Answer (score 1):

[The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/text.html#edef-STRONG) doesn't say you have to. [The validator](http://validator.w3.org) is happy for you to have it in some other block-level container.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that "- end -" is a case for an `<hr/>` or a `p:after{content:"-end-"}`

Comment: p:after{content:"-end-"} is supported in all browsers?

Comment: No, it isn't, but if it is purely presentational this may not be critical.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the lower is more semantically correct as the `<strong>` tag is not a block level element which means you need to wrap it in the `<p>`. Otherwise I'm sure you will come across issues when you try and validate your HTML.

Comment: There are plenty of elements other than `p` that a `strong` element may be a child of. Also, "Validity" and "Semantics" are very different things.

Comment: Agreed. But as far as using just <strong>This is Bold</strong> you will come into issues with validating your HTML.

Comment: In the example given in the question, the `strong` element is a child of `div` element … which is valid.